# SQL Server format file - can I use to generate create table statement?

Tags: sql-server, xml, reverse-engineering, ddl, bcp

I have been given 35 SQL Server format files (both xml and non-xml) and associated data files. What I do not have is the DDL needed to create the 35 tables.

Is there any way to reverse engineer the format files to generate a create table statement? I know I can look at each file and manually do this, but trying to see if there is an easier way...

Comment: Of course there is. The XML format files will be the easiest. You have the data type and their length... therefore you have the table. Create A Format File - [Creating an XML Format File | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server#creating-an-xml-format-file) the entire page will help you

Comment: For non-xml you can just paste them into Excel and use formulas to generate the code for you. Crude, but effective.

Comment: Can you put the format files somewhere we can access them?

Answer (score 3):

Assume that your bcp xml format file looks similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="NativeFixed" LENGTH="4"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="NativePrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="1"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="3" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="8" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="150" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Id" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Type" xsi:type="SQLSMALLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Language" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="Value" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="Subject" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

This sql script generates sql statement to create table from bcp xml format file.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @filePath NVARCHAR(256) = N'C:\table.xml'
      , @tableName SYSNAME = N'#myTable'
      , @xmlData XML
      , @sqlCmd NVARCHAR(1000)
      , @dmlQuery NVARCHAR(max) = N''
      , @crlf NVARCHAR(2) = CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10)
DECLARE @columns table(id INT NOT NULL, colName SYSNAME NOT NULL, dataType VARCHAR(50), [Length] INT NULL, [Precision] INT NULL, [Scale] INT NULL)
DECLARE @sql table(s VARCHAR(1000), id INT IDENTITY)

SET @sqlCmd = N'SET @xmlData = (
  SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (
    BULK ''' + @filePath  + ''', SINGLE_BLOB
  ) AS xmlData
)';
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCmd, N'@xmlData XML OUTPUT', @xmlData = @xmlData OUTPUT

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
(
    DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format',
            'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi
)
INSERT INTO @columns
SELECT  x.c.value('@SOURCE', 'INT'),
        x.c.value('@NAME', 'varchar(100)'),
        SUBSTRING(x.c.value('@xsi:type', 'varchar(100)'), 4, 20),
        ISNULL(y.f.value('@MAX_LENGTH', 'INT'), y.f.value('@LENGTH', 'INT')),
        x.c.value('@PRECISION', 'INT'),
        x.c.value('@SCALE', 'INT')
FROM @xmldata.nodes('/BCPFORMAT/ROW/COLUMN') x(c)
JOIN @xmldata.nodes('/BCPFORMAT/RECORD/FIELD') y(f) ON x.c.value('@SOURCE', 'INT') = y.f.value('@ID', 'INT')

UPDATE @columns SET dataType = REPLACE(dataType, 'VARYCHAR', 'VARCHAR');
UPDATE @columns SET dataType = REPLACE(dataType, 'DATETIM4', 'SMALLDATETIME');

INSERT INTO  @sql(s) VALUES ('create table ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' (')

INSERT INTO  @sql(s)
    SELECT @crlf 
        + QUOTENAME([colName])+ N' ' + [dataType] 
        + IIF([Length] IS NOT NULL AND [dataType] LIKE 'N%CHAR', '(' + CAST([Length]/2 AS VARCHAR) + ')', 
          IIF([Length] IS NOT NULL AND [dataType] LIKE '%CHAR', '(' + CAST([Length] AS VARCHAR) + ')', 
          IIF([Length] IS NULL AND [dataType] LIKE '%CHAR', '(MAX)', 
          IIF([Precision] IS NOT NULL AND [dataType] = 'DECIMAL', '(' + CAST([Precision] AS VARCHAR) + IIF([Scale] IS NOT NULL, ',' + CAST([Scale] AS VARCHAR), '') + ' )'
         , '') ) ) ) + ',' 
    FROM @columns
    ORDER BY id;


UPDATE @sql 
   SET s = left(s, len(s) - 1) 
 WHERE id = scope_identity()

INSERT INTO @sql(s) VALUES( ')' )

SELECT @dmlQuery += s 
  FROM @sql 
 ORDER BY id;

PRINT @dmlQuery -- sql query CREATE TABLE ….
```

Then you can bulk into the newly created table

```
BULK INSERT [#myTable] FROM 'C:\table.dat' WITH (KEEPIDENTITY, DATAFILETYPE='native', FORMATFILE = 'C:\table.xml');
```

Comment: You should note that this script won't handle the subtle difference in bcp format between `int not null` and `int null` columns

Answer (score 0):

Despite this being a five year old post, it worked well for me in SQL 2019 (thank you).  I did have to make a few tweaks to it to suit my needs because certain limitations were found to exist that caused issues.

First, the print statement at the end is limited to 4000 bytes and I had some tables where the create statement code exceeded 7000 so I changed the last line to PRINT CAST(@dmlQuery AS NTEXT) which I believe allows 16000 bytes of output.

Second, the xml file had a couple native data types that were not handled so I worked around that by making an update to the temp table @sql right after the line that inserts the close parenthesis as follows:
update @sql set s = replace(s,'] UNIQUEID','] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER')
update @sql set s = replace(s,'] FLT8','] FLOAT')

Once those changes were added I was able to create the tables from the bcp xml format files.

Again, I dont know for certain whether the above tweaks have to do with a newer version of SQL or not but passing along in case anyone else runs into the same issue.